# What should be the correct file permissions for the laravel Storage folder?

Tags: laravel

Yesterday, after deploying a Laravel application on AWS EC2 Ubuntu server, when I tried to run it, I received and error message:

```
The stream or file "/var/www/vhosts/silkweb.ca/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied.
```

After playing with ownership and file permission of the Storage folder, my application started working. The current file permissions are 755 for the Storage folder as well as for all its subfolder. I am not sure, if this is correct or it may cause any security implications.

When I asked a question about the file permission to **chatGPT**, it provided the following answer, which talks about 644 permissions for some files.

*In Laravel, the "storage" folder contains files that your application needs to read from or write to at runtime. The correct file permissions for the "storage" folder will depend on the specific requirements of your application and the security policies in place on your server. However, here is a common set of file permissions for the "storage" folder in Laravel:*

*Directories within "storage" should have the "rwxr-xr-x" (755) permission. This allows the owner (usually the user running the web server) to read, write, and execute files within the directory, and allows group members and other users to read and execute files within the directory.*

*Files within "storage" should have the "rw-r--r--" (644) permission. This allows the owner to read and write the file, and allows group members and other users to read the file.*

*It's important to note that these permissions only apply to the "storage" directory itself and its immediate contents, not to any subdirectories or files within it. If you have subdirectories or files within "storage" that require different permissions, you may need to adjust the permissions accordingly.*

*Also, if your application needs to write to files within the "storage" folder at runtime (for example, if you are using the Laravel file cache driver or session driver), the directory permissions may need to be adjusted to allow the web server user (e.g. www-data) to write to those files. In that case, you could set the directory permission to "rwxrwxr-x" (775) and ensure that the web server user is a member of the group that owns the "storage" directory.*

I would like to know the recommended (and safe) file permission settings for the Storage folder and its subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility):

> When using the `local` driver, `public` visibility translates to `0755` permissions for directories and `0644` permissions for files. You can modify the permissions mappings in your application's `filesystems` configuration file:

```php
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
    'permissions' => [
        'file' => [
            'public' => 0644,
            'private' => 0600,
        ],
        'dir' => [
            'public' => 0755,
            'private' => 0700,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks. I am storing documents in AWS S3, however, I believe that errors are being stored in Storage/logs/laravel.log . My question is that do I need to make any changes to the permissions for the directory and any files already available in the Storage folder. (Currently, it is 755 for all folders, subfolders and files in the Storage folder.